# Service Fabric errors with Reverse Proxy when losing a node

Tags: reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric

We have an Azure Service Fabric instance behind a load balancer. The services in the cluster either call out to external services or to other services in the cluster via the reverse proxy. The reverse proxy works well and sends the request onto an available node. All is good.

If we upgrade a service or gracefully through Powershell restart a process or a node, then all is good also.

However, If I simply reboot a VM in the scale set, all hell breaks loose.

I think what is happening is that the Load Balancer is correctly sensing the machine is down and stopping requests to that node. However, the reverse proxy is not understanding the node is unavailable, although it is clearly shown that way in SF Explorer, and it is still sending some requests to the dead server.

How should this work? Has anyone else had this experience? Any suggestions as to our problem and solution?

R.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the source code of the RP here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric-reverse-proxy

This issue indicates that the ASF-RP does not support health probing and therefore could route to service that is not healthy.

https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/607

There are numerous reasons as to why my company switched to Traefik - deployed as a Guest Executable. This has support for health probes, and numerous other features - such as header switched routing etc. The ASF OOTB proxy is great for getting you up and running quickly, it just falls over when you hit more advanced scenarios.

https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric